# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - inserting a SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem with inserting SQLite with Helper into my project. 
There's an error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: Java nullpointer exception.
I spend a few days for searching a issue to fix this and I can't.

Here's a code of MainActivity:

```
private Database myDBAdapter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDBAdapter.open();
        //TODO Any database operations
        myDBAdapter.close();
```

and Database class:

```
 public Database(Context _context){
            context = _context;
            DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(_context, DB_NAME, null, DB_Version, null);
        }



        public Database open(){
            db = DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;

        }
        public void close(){
            db.close();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never instantiate your `myDBAdapter` object, and hence the NPE at the line `myDBAdapter.open();`.

```
private Database myDBAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();
        myDBAdapter.close();
```

Comment: Wow, genial tip :) Thank You so much :)

Comment: @Algeroth Declaration and initialization are two different things. You should read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html